# VPN site-to-site client doesn´t get ping reply

Tags: vpn, ping

I have 4 servers created on OVHcloud, all run Ubuntu 22. They compose simple test network with these IP:

```
Client_A:
    ens3 - public IP
    ens4 - 10.200.0.1

Server_B:
    ens3 - public IP
    ens4 - 10.200.0.2

Server_C:
    ens3 - public IP
    ens4 - 10.201.0.1

Client_D:
    ens3 - public IP
    ens4 - 10.201.0.2
```

I created ipsec tunnel between Server_B and Server_C, using StrongSwan. It was successfully established, as can be seen in output of ipsec status command ...

```
B_to_C{1}: INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP SPIs: c333a692_i ca3c274b_o B_to_C{1}: 10.200.0.0/16 === 10.201.0.0/16  
C_to_B{2}: INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP SPIs: ca3c274b_i c333a692_o C_to_B{2}: 10.201.0.0/16 === 10.200.0.0/16
```

I added static route to Client_A

```
10.201.0.0/16 via 10.200.0.1 dev ens4
```

... and to Client_D as well...

```
10.200.0.0/16 via 10.201.0.1 dev ens4
```

I set up /etc/sysctl.conf to contain net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 on both ipsec servers.

When I ping from Client_A to Client_D, there is no response, but as I run tcpdump on Server_B, it shows, that Client_D sends echo reply to Client_A, but for some reason, it stops on Server_B and doesn´t reach Client_A.

```
10.201.0.2 > 10.200.0.2: ICMP echo reply, id 56, seq 2, length 64
```

When I ping from Server_B to Client_D, Server_B gets reply correctly.

So please, would somebody explain, why the reply to echo request from Client_A to Client_D cannot reach the originator - Client_A?

There are no firewall rules, that would block the packets